# FreeRadius 3.0.1 Unlang Policy to Dynamically match User -> Client -> LDAP group

Tags: freeradius

I have my Radius working with AD + Google OTP working fine.  What I am trying to accomplish now is to specify user-to-client-to-ADgroup in a policy and/or unlang within the post-auth.

**How it works today:**

- client performs request
- Radius sends first half of the password to AD
- Radius sends the second half of the password to Google OTP
- If both come back good, then auth is successful
- Post-auth does some checking if user is memberof ADgroup -> assign
  class -> accept
- OR if not part of ADgroup -> reject

**The part I need assistance with** is I have over 30 sites with equipment in each one.  We distinguish our users based on per site access.  E.g. NetworkAdmin01 is allowed to access site01 but not site02.
So the only way I can think of doing this:

- Each site has it's own virtual server (VS)
- Each client has the "virtual server" attribute set
- Within each VS there is post-auth unlang like:

  ```
   if (LDAP-Group == "NetworkAdmins_site01") {
     [do something] (update control, update reply, etc..)
    else
     reject
  ```

This setup would require me to have 30+ VS running on the Radius and is not manageable.

If I was able to run this within a few VS (separated based on equipment vendor)Want within the post-auth to grant/assign based on;

```
   if (%{client:shortname} =~ /regex/) #grab the portion of the variable between "." (site01)
    if (LDAP-Group =~ /regex/) # grab the portion of the variable after last "_" (site01)
      if (%{0} == %{1}) {
        if (LDAP-Group == NetworkAdmins_site01) {
          update reply {
            Juniper-Local-User-Name := "admins_group"
          }
         }
        else {
          update control {
            Auth-type := "Reject"
          }
         }
       }
       }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of looking around, it appears that runtime dynamic variables are the biggest limitation to building any type of policies/rules.
so I went a different direction.  I have basically matched the NAS-IP-Address to the IP subnet/site I expect the request to come from.
So this is placed into the Post-Auth section of each VS.  Not the most manageable way when you have 30+ sites but, best I could find at this point (without running 30+ VS).

```
      #  SITE01 site
      if (&NAS-IP-Address < 10.1.0.0/16) {  
        if (LDAP-Group == "Radius_NetworkAdmins_SITE01") {
          update reply {
            Juniper-Local-User-Name := "ad-super-users"
          }
        }
        elsif (LDAP-Group == "Radius_NetworkAdminsRO_SITE01") {
          update reply {
            Juniper-Local-User-Name := "ad-readonly-users"
          }
        }
      }
      #  SITE02 site
      if (&NAS-IP-Address < 10.2.0.0/16) {  
        if (LDAP-Group == "Radius_NetworkAdmins_SITE02") {
          update reply {
            Juniper-Local-User-Name := "ad-super-users"
          }
        }
        elsif (LDAP-Group == "SG_Uni_Radius_NetworkAdminsRO_SITE02") {
          update reply {
            Juniper-Local-User-Name := "ad-readonly-users"
          }
        }
      }
    else {
      update reply {
        Reply-Message := "Not authorized to access this system"
      }
      update control {
        Auth-Type := "Reject"
      }
    }
    #
      Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
        -sql
        attr_filter.access_reject
        eap
        remove_reply_message_if_eap
        }
      }
      Post-Auth-Type Challenge {
      }
#
    pre-proxy {
    }
#
    post-proxy {
      eap
    }
```